# How to make a template that have a list with divisions based on sub_category?

Tags: django, templates

I have a query in django that:

- gets the current category.
- based on that gets all it's sub categories
- then make a query to get the articles that are contained in the above sub_categories

My template should be displaying all articles with divisions based on those sub_categories.

How might I do it?

thanks (:

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {% ifchanged article.category %}
        <p>{{ article.category }}</p>
    {% endifchanged %}
    <a href="#" class="item">
        <span>{{article.code}}</span>
        <span class="large">{{article.description}}</span>
        <span>{{article.family_name}}</span>
        <span class="small">{{article.last_cost|floatformat:2}}</span>
        <span class="small">{{article.sell_price1|floatformat:2}}</span>
        <span class="small">{{article.stock|floatformat:2}}</span>
        <span class="last">{{article.stock_consignments|floatformat:2}}</span>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant models to your question?

Comment: Category model that might have sub_categories (relationship on itself) and a Category might have 1 or more Articles. But the problem here is not more that. the article.category when used in the template is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary in your view code, with one entry per category that contains a list of the articles. So it looks something like this:

```
{ 'category1' : [ <all articles for this category> ], ... }
```

Will make it much easier for the template code.

Comment: but I would have to make a single query for each sub_category?

Comment: @Totty I would do the splitting in the view code, using list comprehension.

Comment: ok.. the problem was another. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150302/django-select-related-or-select-fields-from-the-other-table-when-making-a-join-w